# Error: Could not find or load main class in python

Tags: java, python

I am trying to run this command in Python:

```
java JSHOP2.InternalDomain logistics
```

It works well when I run it in cmd.

I wrote this in Python:

```
args = ['java', 
        r"-classpath", 
        r".;./JSHOP2.jar;./antlr.jar", 
        r"JSHOP2.InternalDomain", 
        thisDir+"/logistics" 
       ] 
    proc = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE) 
    proc.communicate()
```

I have the jar files in the current directory.

but I got this error: 
Error: Could not find or load main class JSHOP2.InternalDomain

Does anyone know what the problem is? can't it find the jar files?

Comment: You probably want to set the current working dir for the process (the `cwd` keyword argument to `Popen()`).

Comment: how should I do that?

Comment: Set the `cwd=` keyword argument to the directory you want `.` to represent in the classpath. That or use absolute paths in the classpath.

Comment: The directory I want is the current path because I have the jar files in the current directory. When I run this script it works fine, but when another python function calls this script it gives me the error.

Comment: thisDir =  os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), this directory contains the jar files. I added this path to CLASSPATH too. Still doesn't work

Comment: *when another Python function calls this script*; that's still all within the same process. Figure out what environment changes that other context introduced. Look at `os.environ` and the current working directory.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Tanx! the problem was working directory. It is solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't count on the current working directory always being the same when running your Python code. Explicitly set a working directory using the `cwd` argument:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                        cwd='/directory/containing/jarfiles')
```

Alternatively, use absolute paths in your `-classpath` commandline argument. If that path is `thisDir`, then use that:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                        cwd=thisDir)
```